# How to use hardware breakpoints in LLDB?

Tags: breakpoints, lldb, watchpoint

I'm playing with the lldb Python API to set a watchpoint and printing it:

```
Watchpoint 1: addr = 0x700005451ff0 size = 8 state = enabled type = w
    declare @ '/Users/stringer/test.c:945'
    new value: 0x000000011a4b1000
    hw_index = -1  hit_count = 0     ignore_count = 0
```

From the source code:

```
With -1 representing an invalid hardware index.
```

I can see that the performance is quite slow too. Is there something that can be done to use hardware breakpoints?

Edit:

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/lldb/blob/76c0545e7f24cd6636df61292472df64cfa2900e/tools/debugserver/source/MacOSX/x86_64/DNBArchImplX86_64.cpp#L856) it seems that the watchpoint must be created with either read or write set to `True` which is my case.